# How can I hide the display of a page until the ng-include elements are available?

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following code block:

```
<section id="content">
    <div class="block-border">
        <div data-ng-controller="AdminGridContentController">
            <ng-include src="'/Content/app/admin/partials/grid-content-base.html'"></ng-include>
            <ng-include src="'/Content/app/admin/partials/table-content.html'"></ng-include>
            <ng-include src="'/Content/app/admin/partials/modal-content.html'"></ng-include>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This works but when it displays first of all it displays a "block-border" which in my case is a shadow border. Then after a short time the inside contents display.

Is there a way I can make it so the outer `<DIV>` does not show until the inside includes are ready?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yo should try `ngCloak`:

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak

so... in your case:

```
<section id="content">
    <div class="block-border">
        <div data-ng-controller="AdminGridContentController" ng-cloak>
            <ng-include src="'/Content/app/admin/partials/grid-content-base.html'"></ng-include>
            <ng-include src="'/Content/app/admin/partials/table-content.html'"></ng-include>
            <ng-include src="'/Content/app/admin/partials/modal-content.html'"></ng-include>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Wow, this has always bothered me. Glad I finally googled it--had no idea the fix would be so easy!

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

*HTML*

```
<div data-ng-controller="AdminGridContentController">
     <ng-include src="'/Content/app/admin/partials/grid-content-base.html'" ng-show="isLoaded"></ng-include>
     <ng-include src="'/Content/app/admin/partials/table-content.html'" ng-show="isLoaded"></ng-include>
     <ng-include src="'/Content/app/admin/partials/modal-content.html'" ng-show="isLoaded"></ng-include>
</div>
```

*Javascript*

```
yourApp.controller('AppController', ['$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope,) {
    $scope.isLoaded = false;
    $rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(event) {
        $scope.isLoaded = true;
    });
}]);
```

*References*

- [ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow)
- [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude)

Answer (score 1):

The `ng-include` directive raises an `$includeContentLoaded` event. You could use that to set a value which in turn  controls a `ng-show` directive placed on the block-border element.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js#L178

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude -- docs are more helpful than source code

Comment: yep, it wasn't documented at the time of writing though :)

Comment: 3 months ago? The first comment on that page is a year old.

Comment: yes but the $includeContentLoaded event was not documented :)